Celery apps are remaining in background for weeks (memory footprint increases accordingly)
I am fairly new to celery, and have some celery workers and some apps are started with a service with a line such as this:
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

and
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=600 --concurrency=5 -Q 'myqueue'"

I am not sure why, but I find several lines like that in my
ps -ef | grep ${CELERY_APP}
Some of them are weeks old, and they seem to increase their ram footprint as time goes by.
Also, the ram footprint seems to be related with the underlying ${CELERY_APP} (apps with larger footprint will lead to "hung" processes that have larger memory footprint after -say- a week, than otehr processes for apps with smaller footprint)
Would anyone have any idea why this is happening and what can I check to fix this?
(I don't think it matters, but in case it does, rabbitmq is under the hood)

If you suspect this to be a programming issue as it would be required for a Stack Overflow question, please show us how to reproduce: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Check the output of sudo dmesg and see whether OOM handler killed some of your worker processes. If that happened it means that your machine at some point ran out of memory and system decided to kill particular Celery worker process. It also means that you have a memory leak somewhere. Celery can be configured to replace worker process with a new one after N executed tasks - something people often use when they have memory leaks. Also, do not use celery multi, rather run Celery worker standalone. You can try to run it in detached mode for starters.

Thank you @DejanLekic, I use multi tho because I have a multi-worker environment and I can't get rid of that requirement. will look into your other suggersion tho :)
